# Расширение Simple React Snippets для VC не работает

Tags: visual-studio-code

У меня перестали работать расширения Simple React Snippets в vs code. Первый раз устанавливал, работало. Сейчас вдруг перестало.
Ввожу команды imr, imrc, impt и др. а расширение мне их не выдает. Пока только удалял и снова ставил, так же установил более мощное ES7 React/Redux он тоже не работает.
Предположу, что нужно что-то в настройках поставить. Вот только когда не знаешь, тыкать куда попало не хочется. Что можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в последней версии VSCode, нужно ждать исправления.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson
Нет. Не в версии дело. В других проектах все работает.